# Which term to use for real numbers in the [0, 1] interval?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for referring to a real number in the [0, 1] interval? Examples:

(Sorry for dumby question, but I don't find resources!)

> 1
>   0.5
>   .3
>   0.9

I've heard of `decimal`, but I think it's on the [0, 1) interval.

Comment: is this a computer science question ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Nope, I'm asking for a term that I can use to refer to floating numbers (w/o decimal number) that start from `0` and end at `1`.

Comment: so an interval ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Yea. I need a term for the { 0, ..., 1 } interval.

Comment: I don't know of any particular name, but $0.9999999\dots$, usually denoted $0.\bar{9}$, **is** equal to $1$. (also, the notation for the interval is $[0,1]$, not $\{0,\dots,1\}$ which would refer usually to all integers between $0$ and $1$ included, i.e. the set $\{0,1\}$)

Comment: @ClementC. Nice! I never heard about that. If so `decimal` is a good term...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_interval is the interval [01] including the endpoints

Comment: @Matheus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Comment: Thanks, this helped me as well.

Comment: @Matheus By any chance are you simply referring to the interval $[0,1)$ where $1$ is not included but every nonnegative number strictly less than $1$ is included?  If so, then this interval does not **have** a maximum value, but saying "the maximum value is 0.9999..." would be plausible as a naive way to describe this concept.  (Most people who haven't studied analysis would not realize it is possible for a bounded set to not have a maximum.)

Comment: In oreder to specify that $x$ is a real number in the interval $[0,1]$, one usually writes $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @ErickWong The interval [0, 1)  was what I though decimal numbers were composed of. I really want to include 1.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks, I'll remind me about this expression. Actually I need a term for direct reference.

Comment: The capital letter $ I$ is often used for the set $[0,1$], especially when it needs to be mentioned repeatedly. But it is not good to use $I$ for $[0,1] $without saying so, as it is not a universal convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positive fractional numbers are those in $[0,1[$.

Decimal is, properly speaking, related to the rapresentation of a number, not to the number itself (the decimal representation) to distinguish it from other rapresentations (binary, hexadecimal, ...).

There is not a single english word to name a generic number in $[0,1]$: you can say positive fractional or unity.

Please note that, $0.\bar{9}=1$ exactly. It is not an approximation.

Comment: This answer is not correct, and don't answer the question... There are reals there that you are not considering

Answer (score 1):

If you are just searching for a word: You could write

"Real numbers (rational or irrational) in the interval $[0,1]$ will be called *fractions* for short."